# Side Effects of Function in Python

Tags: python, side-effects

I'm a pretty novice programmer, and currently trying to solve the "Palindrome Linked List" program on Leetcode. My idea is to write a nested function called "reverse" which reverses the linked list, and then simply perform a comparison. Code is attached below.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> bool:
        def reverse(arg):
            #function to return a reverse of the linked list
            curr, prev = arg, None
            while curr:
                nxt = curr.next
                curr.next = prev
                prev = curr
                curr = nxt
            return prev
        original = head
        reversed_ = reverse(original)
        return head == reversed_
```

After some debugging, I've determined that my `reverse()` function seems to be working properly. However when I call reverse:

```
reversed_ = reverse(original)
```

It has the unintended side effect of changing the value of both `original` AND `head`. When I run this code on the following input:

```
head = [1,2,2,1]
```

then right when I get to the very last line, `reversed_` has the correct value but head has been altered by the function call to be just

```
head = [1]
```

I understand that this is what's known as a side effect, and I now for the first time get the appeal of functional programming. What can I do to remedy this situation? I tried introducing the `original` variable to deal with this, to no avail.

Comment: `original = head` creates `original` as a new variable name, but that name refers to the same object as `head`: it doesn't create a second linked list. To proceed the way you want to, you would need to write a function to **copy** the list.

Comment: As a general reference on how names and objects relate to each other in Python, see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @slothrop no need to write a function, it's quite easy to copy a list.  `original = head[:]` will do it.

Comment: @MarkRansom this is a linked list, not a native Python list. `head` is a ListNode, so `head[:]` isn't going to work. (And simply copying the one node wouldn't be enough anyway.)

Comment: @slothrop I really wish Python called their lists arrays like normal languages.  It would be so much less confusing.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I now see why my attempt at using `original` didn't work. Is there a way to bypass that strategy of copying the linked list `head`? Meaning is there a way I can pass `head` to the function `reverse` without having its value changed?

Comment: Right, you could make your `reverse` return a reversed copy of the list (rather than reversing it in place). But ultimately, there has to be some copying of nodes somewhere if you want to keep your original input list unchanged.

Comment: @MarkRansom Python calls its arrays `array` - calling them `list` would be as confusing as calling its `list` an `array`. The confusion is caused by people understanding 'list' to imply 'linked list'.

Comment: Also, note that wrapping your funcgtions in a `Solution` class is somewhat starnge to Python ways: if you don't need a class, don't write one.
Just if your automatic testing platform requires a class with this name you should write that.

Comment: Is explicitly implementing a linked list a requirement (say for a school assignment)? Python already has native lists that work like linked lists. It may not make a lot of practical sense to implement a linked list in Python like this.

Comment: @Grismar it looks like `array` is a relatively recent addition to Python compared to the built-in basic types.  On the other hand the common terms array and list had distinct meanings long before Python was born.

Comment: If you consider Python 1.4 "relatively recent", then sure @MarkRansom - the Python Foundation considers anything before 1.4 "ancient" though, since it's literally the very first version of Python for which [documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/) is available today. It had `array` and `list` and was released in 1996.

Comment: @Grismar sorry I couldn't find any documentation for it earlier than 2.7.  That's the version where they backported important additions to Python 3.

Comment: Documentation for most versions of Python can be found here https://www.python.org/doc/versions/ - you'll find that arrays and lists (as a sequence type) have consistently featured in the language all the way back to the very early ones. And as early as version 1.4, Python does a very good job of relating them: "Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is constrained." - those constraints allow for the type of behaviour developers will know coming from languages like C, while the `list` sequence type is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of your code:

```
        original = head
        reversed_ = reverse(original)
        return head == reversed_
```

The first line assigns the value named 'head' the name 'original', but both 'head' and 'original' are names for the same value (likely a `ListNode`).

The second line calls `reverse` with `original`, but this is the same as calling `reverse(head)`. The `reverse()` function proceeds to change all the `ListNode` objects in the linked list headed by `head`. The result is a reversed linked list, but constructed of the same elements in the original linked list - and since a linked list is defined by its parts, the orginal linked list no longer exists.

As a result, `head == reversed_` will be `false`, as it compares the resulting reversed linked list to the linked list headed by the last element of the reversed linked list. (and that's assuming `ListNode` has `__eq__()` correctly defined on it)

To avoid this, you want to first create a full copy of the linked list, reverse that, and then compare the two resulting linked lists (to follow the logic you came up with). Alternatively, you could construct the reversed linked list by creating copies of the `ListNode` as you go. It's hard to say what the best option would be, as it depends on the implementation of `ListNode`.

Also consider that there may be more efficient solutions that perform the comparison on the original linked list without constructing a copy, especially if you know the length of the linked list.